# Python и DirectInput

Tags: python, directx

Стоит задача - выполнить парочку простых "тасков" а-ля "вывод названий устройств на экран, использующих DirectInput".

Возможна ли сия реализация на Python?

Ибо пытался почитать про DirectInput python (он же directpy), но документации не очень много и сам directpy показался сырым.

И вообще, стоит ли идти этим путём?

Comment: Через сам python хорошо вряд ли выйдет. Только если использовать его как ретранслятор. Что вряд ли вам нужно)